# How do i Jsoup query for the value of a html key/value pair

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

sorry if my terms are off, i havent done this before

Im using jsoup to scrape a single value off a website page,
I am trying to find the `"serialno"` which is stored within this function (java script?)

```
    function set(obj, val)
{
document.getElementById(obj).innerHTML= val;
}
```

called by

```
{set("modelname", "NPort 5650-16");set("mac", "00:90:E8:22:76:F4");set("serialno", "2583");set("ver", "3.3 Build 08042219");setlabel("NPORT");uptime("264 days, 03h:31m:34s");}<
```

i am unsure how i can use jsoup to extract/print the serialno value, which in this case happens to be 2583. ive tried basic commands using `getElementById` but ive never used jsoup before. i am familiar with maps, but not sure how i can manipulate with jsoup, and most of the tutorials online need the actual 'path' to the exact cell within the table (where this info is displayed).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Jsoup to do this. Jsoup can parse HTML, but javascipt is out of its reach and is recognized as text. It can't be executed and selecting things from javascript is not possible.
But if you already have HTML parsed to `Document` and you're looking for an alternative solution you may try to use regular expressions to grab this value.

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse...
        String html = doc.toString();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("set\\(\"serialno\", \"(\\d+)\"\\)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
        if (m.find()) {
            String serialno = m.group(1);
            System.out.println(serialno);
        }
```